# При отключенном интрнете не работает приложение на JPA

Tags: jpa, java

Файл persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="lab4">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <class>model.City</class>
    <class>model.Shop</class>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Консоль:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Provider error. Provider: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createFactory(Persistence.java:175)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:111)
at ui.Main$1.run(Main.java:78)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: <openjpa-1.2.0-r422266:683325 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.util.GeneralException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: file:/C:/Users/kRyptoNite/workspace/lab4/build/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml [Location: Line: 2, C: 251]: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/kRyptoNite/workspace/lab4/build/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 251; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'.
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parseNewResource(XMLMetaDataParser.java:379)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parse(XMLMetaDataParser.java:318)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parse(XMLMetaDataParser.java:295)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parse(XMLMetaDataParser.java:268)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation$ConfigurationParser.parse(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:509)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation.parseResources(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:359)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation.load(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:326)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation.load(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:161)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:77)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:109)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:53)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createFactory(Persistence.java:171)
... 16 more
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at ui.Main.getCities(Main.java:571)
at ui.Main.access$5(Main.java:570)
at ui.Main$2.componentShown(Main.java:121)
at java.awt.Component.processComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Настройки Persistence:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
                props.put("openjpa.ConnectionURL", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Supermarkets");
                props.put("openjpa.ConnectionDriverName", "org.postgresql.Driver");
                props.put("openjpa.ConnectionUserName", "postgres");
                props.put("openjpa.ConnectionPassword", "12345");
                props.put("openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings", "buildSchema");

                emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("lab4", props);
                em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

При подключении к интернету всё работает нормально. При отключенном получаю вышеизложенную ошибку. Может, есть у кого какие догадки? Буду очень признателен за любую помощь.

Comment: А попробуй прогой fiddler4 просмотреть, кто качает и что качает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рискну предположить, что хитрый парсер xml-конфига JPA пытается провалидировать этот самый конфиг согласно схеме, объявленной в `xsi:schemaLocation`, но при отсутствии одключения к интернету не может эту схему скачать. Выходом будет скачать файл схемы по указанному адресу и указать расположение скачанного файла в `xsi:schemaLocation`.

http://echuprina.blogspot.com/2013/03/cannot-find-declaration-of-element.html